# GWT DataGrid: use of CheckboxCell-selection and standard line mode selection at the same time

Tags: gwt

**I'm using a GWT DataGrid with a MultiSelectionModel.**

The selections of the items of the grid should be achieved by

**a) a CheckboxColumn** with a CheckboxCell

and additionally at the same time by

**b) the standard line mode selection-model** (by clicking on the rest of the line).

With the CheckboxColumn the user should be enabled to multi-select different entries. But when clicking somewhere else on the datagrid-lines, a single-line-selection-policy should be done, that means, if a multiple-selection was done before using the checkboxes, this selection should be resetted and only the the clicked line should be selected afterwards.

This is what I have. Does anyone know how to enable CheckBox-Mode and line-selection-mode at the same time?

```
public class JobDataGrid extends DataGrid<Job>
{
    private MultiSelectionModel<Job> selectionModel;

    private Column<Job, Boolean> checkboxColumn;
    private TextColumn<Job> idColumn;
    private TextColumn<Job> titleColumn;
    private TextColumn<Job> timestampColumn;
    private TexTColumn<Job> ...

    public JobDataGrid ()
    {
        super ();

        checkboxColumn = new Column<Job, Boolean> (new CheckboxCell (true, false)) {
            @Override
            public Boolean getValue (Job job)
            {
                // Get the value from the selection model.
                return selectionModel.isSelected (job);
            }
        };
        checkboxColumn.setFieldUpdater (new FieldUpdater<Job, Boolean> () {
            public void update (int index, Job job, Boolean value)
            {
                // Called when the user clicks on a checkbox.
                selectionModel.setSelected (job, value);
            }
        });

        // [...]
        // [...]
        // [...]

        selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<Job> ();
        setSelectionModel (selectionModel); 
        // setKeyboardSelectionPolicy (KeyboardSelectionPolicy.DISABLED);

        // [...]
        // [...]
        // [...]
    }
}
```

I've tried out all 4 variants

```
new CheckboxCell (false, false);
new CheckboxCell (true, false);
new CheckboxCell (false, true);
new CheckboxCell (true, true);
```

but none of them showed up what I need. And I've also played with

```
setSelectionModel (selectionModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.<Job> createCheckboxManager ());
```

Maybe

```
createCustomManager(DefaultSelectionEventManager.EventTranslator<T> translator)
```

would help?

Thanx
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own "checkbox manager" and do what you want there.

```
table.setSelectionModel(selectModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.<DocumentListItemDTO> createCustomManager(
            new DefaultSelectionEventManager.CheckboxEventTranslator<DocumentListItemDTO>() {
                @Override
                public SelectAction translateSelectionEvent(CellPreviewEvent<DocumentListItemDTO> event) {
                    SelectAction action = super.translateSelectionEvent(event);
                    if (action.equals(SelectAction.IGNORE)) {

                        if (!event.getNativeEvent().getCtrlKey() && !event.getNativeEvent().getShiftKey())
                            selectionModel.clear();

                        return SelectAction.TOGGLE;

                    }
                    return action;
                }
            }));
```

Comment: ok thanks, but how to filter for checkboxCell-click-events and line-click-events there?

Answer (score 2):

[Lista's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37791179/3472757) showed up the right direction!

In order to show the usage of `DefaultSelectionEventManager.CheckboxEventTranslator` for which on the web only hardly can be found examples, here is a fully functional solution as requested:

```
setSelectionModel (selectionModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.<Job> createCustomManager (
        new DefaultSelectionEventManager.CheckboxEventTranslator<Job> () {

            @Override
            public SelectAction translateSelectionEvent (CellPreviewEvent<Job> event)
            {
                NativeEvent nativeEvent = event.getNativeEvent ();

                // Determine if we clicked on a checkbox.
                Element target = nativeEvent.getEventTarget ().cast ();
                if ("input".equals (target.getTagName ().toLowerCase (Locale.ROOT)))
                {
                    final InputElement input = target.cast ();
                    if ("checkbox".equals (input.getType ().toLowerCase (Locale.ROOT)))
                    {
                        // Synchronize the checkbox with the current selection state.
                        input.setChecked (event.getDisplay ().getSelectionModel ().isSelected (
                                event.getValue ()));
                        return SelectAction.TOGGLE;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (BrowserEvents.CLICK.equals (nativeEvent.getType ()))
                    {
                        selectionModel.clear ();
                        return SelectAction.SELECT;
                    }
                }
                return SelectAction.IGNORE;
            }
        }));
```